# Get keyboard size with suggestion bar swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift4

In my application I need to get keyboard size for after move the others components to correctly position, now i'm using that code to get height

```
let info:NSDictionary = aNotification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
let kbSize:CGSize = (info.object(forKey: UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey)! as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size
print(kbSize.height)
```

In the first time when keyboard is open the result is 260.0, but this value is size default, without the suggestions/passwords bar height, when I click out and click in the input again the result is 304.0 the value I want...
How I can get 304 since the first click in the input?

Comment: What are the names of the keyboard notifications you register for?

Comment: did you first run the code snippet after viewDidAppear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be listening for changes in the keyboard's size and adjusting the rest of your content that way, since, as you found out, iOS keyboards can change size. You should subscribe to `UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` and/or `UIResponder.keyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` which are notifications which trigger when the keyboard's frame will, or did, change. Here's an example of it in use:

```
// Somewhere in set up code
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidChangeFrame),
    name: UIResponder.keyboardDidChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)

// Function elsewhere in your class
@objc func keyboardDidChangeFrame(_ notification: Notification) {
  guard let kbSize = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]
      as? CGRect else {
    return;
  }

  // Use kbRect as you initially did
}
```

Note that you can use either the `Will` or the `Did` notifications depending on how you want the layout change to look. You can also query both `UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` `UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` to get the keyboard frame before and after the size change, which may be useful if you want to animate your layout along with the keyboard.

Comment: The secret is update the layout when frame of keyboard changed the size...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillChange(notification: Notification) {

        guard let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else { return }

        if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification || notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification {
            view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardSize.height
        } else {
            view.frame.origin.y = 0
        }
    }
}
```

HERE is the [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/erdemildiz/7aeb71709651cec96d8dc3dffc766518)